# I just installed EGit on Eclipse -- but Where is it?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I just installed the EGit plugin for Eclipse, restarted Eclipse and it shows well in the Installed Software list but... I can't find any added menus or access to its features?

What am I missing?

To prove that I am not hallucinating here is a screenshot of the list:

[image: EGit is there!]

But there is no hint or clue in any of the **menus**, **menu items**, **perspectives** or **views** that it's there...

No sign in menus:
[image]

No sign in projects:

[image]

No sign in perspectives:

[image]

Do I need to do some additional configuration somewhere to enable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mystery solved.

It turns out that I mistakenly installed Eclipse JGit instead of Eclipse EGit. Once I selected the EGit package instead:

[image]

Things went fine:

[image]

One letter difference... (E instead of J)

Comment: I can't see "Eclipse EGit" under Eclipse Git Team Provider. I am using http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates as URL in Eclipse Luna

Comment: @Ravi.Kumar Neither can I. It seems as though things have changed since this answer was posted. Very frustrating not being able to get something as simple as a Git plugin installed in Eclipse, but this is typical for this IDE. Wish I could get my entire team to just switch to IntelliJ, or use Git via the command line and be done with these horrid GUIs.

Comment: @Tom Catullo As of now I am using git through terminal. Git also provides a UI for desktop/mac I think that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You just installed JGit, and forgot EGit. JGit is just the Git implementation, but doesn't contain any UI contributions. These are all in the EGit plugin (which should also be available in the Update Site).

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20 :) (see my earlier answer).  Are both JGit **and** EGit needed? There are 3 sub-packages in that EGit package (plus 3 more source packages). Which ones do I really need? +1.

Comment: You need both. JGit contains the Java Git implementation with all commands to work on Git repositories, and EGit provides the whole UI, that you see (you could JGit alone in your own code to work with Git repositories). The EGit Mylyn plugin contains the integration of EGit and Mylyn (such as automatic commit messages, if a Mylyn task is active, or the relation between commits and Mylyn tasks).

Comment: But I already have command-line Git installed working. Why have two? Isn't there a danger that the bugs in the Java version will not be compatible with the bugs in the command-line version? Please clarify and +1 again.

Comment: Because EGit doesn't use the command line Git (licensing is one reason). Maybe there are different bugs in command line Git and in JGit. But i haven't seen so far an incompatibility between command line and J/EGit, even if you use both on the same repository.

Answer (score 2):

is there no new perspective available? Is there no "new -> project from git repository" available?
Usually eclipse plugins work if they're listed.

Cheers

edit:

I just installed jGit as well. Here's what I found:

[image: some image]

To see it go to: Window -> open Perspective -> other

Also on a rightclick on my projects (as in cvs & svn plugins) -> team I find Git support as well.

Cheers again

edit 2: No "new project from git" here as well.

Comment: Nope. See update of screenshots in my original post. I am stumped and thanks +1 for being the 1st one to answer.

Comment: Interestingly, CVS is listed... but I don't want CVS, I want Git. :)

Comment: cvs is default in most eclipse bundles... Sorry, can't help you then, never used that plugin before, only wanted to make sure you didn't overlook something.

Comment: Thanks so much and +1 again. Unfortunately, I wasn't lucky as you were (see screenshot update in my original post). Why the inconsistent results? Did I hit a but in Eclipse? This is so weird (and frustrating).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [Eclipse Classic package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-43-m6/keplerm6) in Kepler (4.3 M6, March 2013) now includes Egit directly (see [all the packages here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php)).

See the [announcement](http://tmober.blogspot.fr/2013/03/eclipse-classic-now-comes-with-egit.html) from [Martin Oberhuber](http://www.blogger.com/profile/02195662278064214049)

> With Kepler M6, we've added [egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) and [Marketplace Client](http://eclipse.org/mpc/) to the [Eclipse Classic package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-43-m6/keplerm6), which is still the most popular of all Eclipse packages. The request adding git to all packages has been open for long, and after driving it with the Eclipse PMC [Markus Knauer](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/author/mknauer/) has helped me make it happen.